# IdentityServer4 protect the SpringBoot API

Tags: spring-boot, identityserver4

I have configured an IdentityServer4 server to protect my API resources.

I have linked my .NET Core based API resource to the Identity Server but I need to know how to link a Java-based API resource.

I have a REST API based on Spring Boot and I need to configure it in a way it validates incoming JWT tokens with the Identity Server.

Currently, I roughly have two ways to validates the jwt tokens.
1. use jwt library(such as the link below)online to validate the jwt tokens.
https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt
2. use the introspect endpoint, but I am not sure if I can use the introspect endpoint like that.

However, I still need some demo or more realistic way to implements the functionality. A short demo will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my update. Already solve thed problem using the introspect endpoint to validate my token with API name and API secret.

Comment: can you provide more details